# Returning array of pointers from function

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I understand that C does not allow functions to return arrays.

I am writing a function that splits a string using a provided delimiter. Given the following memory data:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15

61 61 61 61 61 61 61 62 61 61 61 61 61 61 61 62
^                       ^
First string            Second string
starts here             starts here
```

Currently, using a delimiter of "b" (byte 62), the function identifies memory locations 0 and 8  and sets 7 (delimiter location) to "\0".

How should I return these pointer locations to the caller function?

Comment: An array is essentially just a pointer, and you can return pointers.

Comment: When you look to the right, under the "Related" text, you'll find all kinds of questions already asked and answered... several of which likely can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could return an array of pointers. (pointer to pointer)
variable**

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return multiple values then there are two general options:

- Provide "out" function parameter(s)
- Return a struct

I'm assuming you are returning pointers into storage which was allocated by the caller (e.g. a string that the caller passes in).